# Restangular | CustomPOST : I am unable to make a CORS POST request, with json data object in the body

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest, cors, restangular

I am trying to make a CORS POST request using Restangular in the following manner :

```
//data is a json object
var urlToPost = '/api/deal/update/'+dealId;
return Restangular.all(urlToPost).customPOST(data, '', {}, {
                    "Content-Type": "application/json",
                    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
                    "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "POST, GET, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS"
                        });
```

When I hit the call, the following error appears on the console :

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://55.76.122.145:8080/hulk/api/deal/update/55cd93bd20ce9744aeebff3a. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:9001' is therefore not allowed access.
```

And in the Network tab, I can see a `successful` call with `status 200` being fired with `OPTION` method.

How to go about it? What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message spells this out for you:

> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:9001' is therefore not allowed access.

The **server** must **respond** to the OPTION request with a **response** including an `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header that tells the browser that the website providing the JavaScript is allowed access.

`Access-Control-Allow-Origin` and `Access-Control-Allow-Methods` are not **request** headers. You can't write JavaScript that gives itself permission to read data from other people's websites. That would be silly.

Comment: So, I need to make changes on the server side, isn't it ? But I am getting a 200 status success response from the OPTION call. Does that not mean that everything is fine on the server side ?

Comment: "So, I need to make changes on the server side, isn't it ?" — Yes. "But I am getting a 200 status success response from the OPTION call. Does that not mean that everything is fine on the server side ?" — It means that as far as the server is concerned, everything is fine. The browser is then going "Oh, the server didn't also say I have permission to give the response to Some Other Site" so I won't.